# How can I show a list within a list in a report?

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, list, report, categories

I'm using the standard reporting engine in a MVC application (.rdlc files) to generate a report.

Basically I have a list of items that need to be displayed in a table... but that list of items contains a list that also needs to be displayed.

A good example of what I am trying to achieve is categorization. Think of it this way:

I have a list of categories with a list of products in the category. The report needs to be something like this:

```
Category A
Product 1 Name      Product 1 Description    Price
Product 2 Name      Product 2 Description    Price
Product 3 Name      Product 3 Description    Price

Category B
Product 4 Name      Product 4 Description    Price
```

and so on.... 
I have the classes setup the way they need to be and the report data source is a list that is returned from a function that fetches the info with some parameters. I know how to display the list of categories, but not the list within them.

So the question is, how can i display a child list for a record in the main list in a report?

EDIT
here is an example data structure for my example scenario

```
public class Category
{
    public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    public List<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any of those who may find this question in search of the answer, I found it here

http://forums.asp.net/p/1432888/3224866.aspx#3224866